# How to re-enable OneDrive in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

Last year (or the previous year), I upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 7 from free upgrade option.
At that time I never use Microsoft Onedrive, so I disabled it.
(I found that I cannot uninstall it, only can disable it using some registry editing or something like that)

Now I want to use OneDrive but cannot recall how I disabled it.
I installed OneDrive through Microsoft Store, but it's only an app while I need a local folder that are automatically synced with online OneDrive storage.

Anybody knows?

Comment: If you cannot tell us how you disabled it, it will be difficult, for us to tell you how to revert the process.

Answer (score 9):

Check the following registry settings:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\OneDrive      
Name: DisableFileSyncNGSC    
Type: DWORD   
Value: 1
```

Set the value to 0 for enabling OneDrive, 1 to disable it.

If you are not using Group Policy, check the setting under:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\OneDrive
```

Comment: You have the values backwards. It should be `1` to disable it and `0` to enable it.

Answer (score 2):

Search in your c:drive for OneDriveSetup.exe. Run this.
Depending on what you did to disable it, this may not work, but it did fine for me after I decided to re-enable, not having recalled how I disabled it.

Comment: Like the OP, I couldn't remember the steps I'd taken to disable Onedrive, but running the .exe did the trick (whereas changing the value in the registry didn't).

Answer (score 0):

If you login to [onedrive.live.com](https://ondrive.live.com)
You can run the "Get the OneDrive apps" at the bottom of the left side menu.
This will re-enable OneDrive.
[image]